# Automation testing for postgres database

Tags: java, database, postgresql, testing, automation

I am testing this api that creates databases/tables in postgres. For automated testing, i was thinking along the lines of, having a setup method that creates a database with tables setup and populated with required data (1000 entries/rows).

I was thinking of an elegant way of doing this? Any thoughts apart from *writing code that loops over 1000 times and writing data stored in a csv to postgres table*?

Comment: What exactly is your question? This sounds like water cooler conversation and not a specific code-related question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Honestly CSV, XML, or any other structured format seems fine to me. Is there a reason you *don't* want to do that? Using the [pg_dump](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/app-pgdump.html) command to export data from an existing DB and using [pg_restore](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/app-pgrestore.html) could be a good option too.

Your other idea about writing code to generate the data isn't bad either. The benefit of writing code is that your test isn't coupled to a data file.

Also, I would take a look at the [H2](http://www.h2database.com/html/main.html) database because it has PostgreSQL compatibility mode, and you can actually embed it in your unit/integration tests instead of relying on a PostgreSQL server to be set up and configured in your tests. We've used H2 to test our PostgreSQL app, and it's worked well. The downside is you can't be 100% sure that just because your test passes against H2 that it will against PostgreSQL.

Comment: Thank you for your response. Will take a look at H2. Was looking to see if there are any tools out there that help in quick setup of database and data. :)

Answer (score 0):

If you really prefer to use postgresql (instead of H2) for testing you could use liquibase. It's a database schema management tool that supports (among others) bulk loading data from csv (http://www.liquibase.org/documentation/changes/load_data.html).

It also offers spring integration if your application use it.